# FizzBuzz solution in an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, fizzbuzz

I have been given the classic FizzBuzz test to do. However, the problem has an extra task which is to display the results in an ArrayList. I know that you can't just stick an integer and string values together in a list. Hence, this is causing problems for me.

I have made an attempt on converting the numbers gotten from the loop to string however, it became too complicated and I thought maybe I was over-complicating things. Or maybe I am doing something wrong for an easy task such as this to be so time-consuming.

Below I have included the most recent code I have tried and the guide comments I was given.

1. Implement the loop that will take the List Range and parse for the values to solve FizzBuzz.
2. You will need to add a successfully value within the loop to the Private Class variable 'private List range'.
3. As an example, while looping 3 will equal fizz which should be added to the fizzBuzzList.
4. The two private variables have been set below for you to hold both the list and the FizzBuzz List.

   ```
   public class FizzBuzz {

   private List range;
   private List fizzBuzzList = new ArrayList();


   public FizzBuzz(int startOfRange, int endOfRange){
       range = IntStream.rangeClosed(startOfRange, endOfRange).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
       fizzBuzzIterator(range);
   }

   public void fizzBuzzIterator(List range){

       for (int i = 1 ; i < range.size(); i++) {

           if (((i % 3) == 0) && ((i % 5) == 0)) {
               fizzBuzzList.add("FizzBuzz");
           }

           else if ((i % 3) == 0) {

               fizzBuzzList.add("Fizz");
           }

           else if ((i % 5) == 0) {
               fizzBuzzList.add("Buzz");
           }

           else {
               fizzBuzzList.add(i);
           }

       }
   }



   public List getFizzBuzzList() {
       return fizzBuzzList;
   }


    }
   ```

Below is the test code which I am supposed to test the results on.

```
public class FizzbuzzTests {

    FizzBuzz fizzBuzz = new FizzBuzz(1,16);

    @Test
    public void fizzBuzzIteratorTest(){
        List<String> minFizzBuzzList = List.of("1","2", "Fizz", "4", "Buzz", "Fizz", "7", "8", "Fizz", "Buzz", "11", "Fizz", "13", "14", "FizzBuzz");
        Assert.assertEquals(fizzBuzz.getFizzBuzzList(), minFizzBuzzList);
    }

}
```

The expected results as I am shown is supposed to be in the format such as [1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz, Fizz, 7, 8, Fizz, Buzz, 11, Fizz, 13, 14, FizzBuzz]. The code written above gives me the results in the same format, however, the difference is that one utilizes "java.util.ArrayList" while other utilizes "java.util.ImmutableCollections$ListN" and thus this gives me an error.

I have been stuck trying to fix this for a while now and I am running out of ideas to try. Any advice would be much helpful and appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `Integer.toString(num);`. Alternatively, use Object as the generic type for the list. Either way, avoid the use of raw types

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `List<String>` and store the numbers as a `String`.  It is not like you need to actually use the numbers to do calculations.

Comment: Just a hint.  Something divisible by both 3 and 5 is divisible by 15.

Answer (score 1):

This solution converts the `int`s to a string using `Integer.toString(int x)` function.

```
List<String> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(startOfRange, endOfRange)
            .mapToObj(this::convert)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);

private String convert(int number) {
    if (((number % 3) == 0) && ((number % 5) == 0)) {
        return "FizzBuzz";
    } else if ((number % 3) == 0) {
        return "Fizz";
    } else if ((number % 5) == 0) {
        return "Buzz";
    } else {
        return Integer.toString(number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store all the values into a `List<String>` rather than a generic and take advantage of `Integer.toString()` to convert the iterator into a `String` to store the value.

The `FizzBuzz` class would look like this in my version:

```
private List<String> fizzBuzzList;

public FizzBuzz(int start, int end){
    fizzBuzzList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.populateFizzBuzz(start, end);
}

private void populateFizzBuzz(int start, int end){
    for (int i = start ; i < end; i++){
        if (((i % 3) == 0) && ((i % 5) == 0)) {
            fizzBuzzList.add("FizzBuzz");
        }
        else if ((i % 3) == 0) {
            fizzBuzzList.add("Fizz");
        }
        else if ((i % 5) == 0){
            fizzBuzzList.add("Buzz");
        }
        else{
            fizzBuzzList.add(Integer.toString(i));
        }
    }
}

public void printFizzBuzz(){
    for (String s : fizzBuzzList){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

I personally did not use Java 8 streams as a preference, and I feel like it complicates a simple problem and makes it more than it is.

You could use this in your `main` or any static method like so:

```
FizzBuzz fb = new FizzBuzz(1, 101);
fb.printFizzBuzz();
```

Note that 101 is **exclusive** and the 1 is **inclusive** so this will iterate from 1 to 100.

Answer (score 0):

And here is a streams version.  It generates a closed range from 1 to 100 and then maps the integers accordingly to the appropriate values using nested ternary operators.

```java
      List<String> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).mapToObj(
            n -> n % 15 == 0 ? "FizzBuzz"
                  : n % 3 == 0 ? "Fizz"
                        : n % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz"
                              : Integer.toString(n)).collect(
                                    Collectors.toList());
      System.out.println(list);
```